# jspm forcing erroneous default

Tags: javascript, jspm

For a project in the past, I made the `public baseURL` of `jspm` point to an `app` folder. However, in any new project, when I run `jspm init` it defaults to the `app` folder, but I don't want this.

I tried looking for documentation on this, but the CLI section of http://jspm.io/docs/ is disabled for some reason.

Any ideas on how to force `jspm` to reinitialize, and ask me all those default questions again? Ideally, I don't want it to "remember" anything between different project initializations.

In the below, you'll note I created a folder called `someProject`, ran `jspm init`, and you'll see it wants to put my `config.js` in a folder outside of my root (in `..\app`). Why? How do I override this?

```
C:\_workspaces\someProject>jspm init
     Initializing package at ../
     Use jspm init . to intialize into the current folder.

warn Running jspm globally, it is advisable to locally install jspm via npm install jspm --save-dev


Configuration file ..\app\config.js doesn't exist, create it? [yes]:C:\_workspaces
```

I know that I can run `jspm init .`, however anytime I run a plain `jspm init` it always uses that old `app` folder. How do I reconcile this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `npm init` to create a new `package.json` file.

```
$ cd someProject
$ npm init
$ jspm init
```

Because, when using the `jspm init` command. The jspm `init` function will check your `package.json` exists in the current folder or not.

You can check the source code for more detail
[JSPM init function](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/lib/core.js#L378)